# Extrude faces problem

Tags: extrude

When I try to extrude the face to make the arms to my character the faces go the same direction but I want to be the opposite direction. Does anyone have any clue how to fix it?

[image: I try to extrude]

Comment: Please could you explain a little more what you mean?  Do you want the other arm to match the extrusions on one arm (mirror modifier)?

Comment: Yes, like i want to extrude the right arm to go to the right and the left arm to the left butt even if i press XX or YY doesn't work

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.9? They changed something about the local and global transform hotkeys, and it threw me off guard too. I think you need to do it 3 times to get local (Ex: YYY). At the very least, you could select both arm "faces", right click, and pick "extrude faces along normals".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yep that worked very nice , thank you a lot, i tried with 3 time to get local but didnt work but with right click and extrude faces along normals worked fine.Thanks a lot man.